# Update records in SQL Server database table after crystal report is exported

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019, insert-update

I am developing a WinForms application using C# and SQL Server 2015. I want to update the records of a table once the crystal report is generated and exported as pdf file.

Details: The user form consist of a ComboBox, and two buttons(button1 to generate the crystal report and other button2 to export the same report in pdf format and save to disk. The report is generated based on the ComboBox value selected by the user.

So far I am able to generate the report and export it to PDF format and save it to disk. The reason why I am using a separate button to export the report is to catch the Export event. So once the report is exported, I want to update the table from which the report is generated.

I have a column called 'exported' in the table, data type is bit. I want this column to set as true for all the records which are generated and exported.

My code is follows.

**Code to generate report on button1 click event**

```
try
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text.Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select Name Tally Category from the list", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                comboBox1.Focus();
                return;

            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString().Length>0)
            {

                rptnametally = new rptNameTally();
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
                con.Open();
                string query = " Select * from tbl_nametally WHERE Item_description = @d2 ";
                cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@d2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 0,"Item_description").Value = comboBox1.Text.ToString();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                da.Fill(myDS, "tbl_nametally");
                rptnametally.SetDataSource(myDS);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rptnametally;
                con.Close();
                
            }

            

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

**Code to export report to pdf format and save to disk on click event of button 2**

```
try
        {
            ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
            DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
            PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
            var myUniqueFileName = string.Format(@comboBox1.Text+"-"+System.DateTime.Now.DayOfYear+".pdf", DateTime.Now.Date);
            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "D:\\"+myUniqueFileName;
            CrExportOptions = rptnametally.ExportOptions;
            {
                CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
                CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
                CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
                CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
            }
            rptnametally.Export();
            MessageBox.Show("Report successfully exported", "Export Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

           
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Up to this point everything is working fine, now once the report is exported I want to update the column 'exported' in table `tbl_nametally` and set value as true against each record which is exported.

I tried doing it like this but am unable to work out how to provide the id of record being updated.

```
con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
con.Open();
string qry1 = "Update tbl_nametally Set exported = @d1 Where Id = " This is the part I am not able to formulate "";
cmd = new SqlCommand(qry1);
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@d1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = true;
cmd.CommandText = qry1;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

My report contain two fields only, Id which is unique and primary key in the table and Name_english which holds the name of a customer.
Any Suggestion and sample code is highly appreciated.

Comment: @DaleK the above 2 piece of code works fine, the last piece of code where I am trying to update the table is the issue.

Comment: @DaleK I am not able to update the table records. `string qry1 = "Update tbl_nametally Set exported =@d1 Where Id = " This is the part I am not able to formulate "";` How do I get the Id of each record which is exported.

Comment: @DaleK to obtain records where clause is different. To be more clear, The ID and Name which is generated in the report has Item_description, and this description will repeat in for other records as well. I dont want to use the same where clause as I dont want every record to set true. Only those records which are generated in the report to be set as true.

Comment: _"Update tbl_nametally Set exported = @d1_ You **know exactly** what value should be set for your column - you don't need a parameter for this. But you do need a parameter for the primary key of the row (or rows?) you want to affect. You did something similar when selecting the row (rows?) in the button1 (a crap name for a control) click event. You need to "save" the ID values and provide them in the update statement.

Comment: @SMor, you are right, I need a parameter for the primary key of the row(or rows) I want to affect. So how do I go for it ??

Comment: Your first block of code uses a parameter to select specific rows. Apply that same concept to your update code block. `string qry1 = "Update tbl_nametally Set exported = 1 where Id = @id"` is the query you need (guessing - i can't see your schema). You then add the parameter correctly and execute it.

Comment: Alternatively (guessing again), you could update the same rows you originally selected with the query "update tbl_nametally set exported = 1 where Item_description = @d2". Is this safe? Think carefully about that! Between the time your app selects those rows and the time your app tries to update them, the description might change or rows might be added/deleted.